# Create hive Views using scala /spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

How do I create multiple table views in Hive programmatically using spark and scala?

1. Drop if a view exists
2. create a view from the table located in the hive.

Comment: Why would you not do that in Hive or IMPALA?

Comment: I need to automate it, as everything is written in spark and scala.

Comment: Can you kindly indicate if this helped you as per the guidelines on this forum? Thx

Answer (score 1):

Since SPARK 2:

```
spark.sql("create or replace view viewSO as select f1.orig as f1_orig, f2.orig as f2_orig, f2.dest as f2_dest from facts f1, facts f2 ")
spark.table("viewSO").printSchema

root
 |-- f1_orig: string (nullable = true)
 |-- f2_orig: string (nullable = true)
 |-- f2_dest: string (nullable = true)
```

I would do it in Hive, Impala, but anyway.

And:

```
spark.sql("drop view viewSO")
```